# iOS 7 - Autolayout - How to change location of views when rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout, uiinterfaceorientation

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape left and right]

I am a bit mixed up with handling UI rotation with autolayout in this situation.  The buttons are not changing size, or distance from an edge, but their location with respect to each other.

How would I get these views to rotate and layout as shown in the images? Also, the view in the portrait is 300 x 300.  However, when rotated into landscape, it must be resized to 300 x 290 in order to fit under the status bar.

I really want to know the BEST way to do this, and different ways to do this.  I have seen POSSIBLE ways such as creating NEW constraints programmatically when the device is rotated as well as having two separate NIBs to be loaded depending on the device rotation orientation.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there are several approaches.

## First approach: using autolayout in a smart way

So you know how wide the square will be and that it will be stuck to the left and top. So set up you autolayouts that it sets left and top offset and width and height. The buttons are stuck y pixels from the bottom and x from the right and have a fixed width and height. Those constraints can always be satisfied.

This works fine for a single idiom like iPad or iPhone.

To get the 290 instead of 300 you need to set an offset to the bottom as well that says > 10 with a priority of say 1000 while the height of <=300 has a priority of 750 and a height of >= 250 (or whatever you like) has a priority of 1000 again. I should play around in a real storyboard to test that correctly, it's not the easiest thing to set up without warnings or problems.

I ended up setting it up with a lot of soft sizes with priorities. The 290 px height has a priority of just 250 for example.

[image: Set up]

## Second approach: flexible size layouts

Next approach is for the new, unlimited sized idiom that is in Xcode 6 already. Clearly this is the future and I would suggest to adapt your app to that. You will have to tell me more about your application and how you want it to scale because there is no real concept of size anymore, just an idea of where the widest and where the narrowest part is.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Any ideas on how to get the buttons to their proper locations?

Comment: That would be the same method only in reverse. I am at work right now, I could do it in a few hours if you want. Basic idea is that you set the offset from the bottom and the right, and if you want to correct from the top you could add another constraint for that. So >= 150px with prio 1000 for top offset, =150px with prio 750 for bottom. Align the buttons together and chain them to the right edge of the screen. Set width and height. Let me know if you get stuck on something!

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.  I don't have the time today, but I will get back ASAP!

Comment: I did get the view working however, and I see what you mean for the buttons

Comment: I did a project with it and basically forced myself to use it all the way. The most important thing is that you should not see any warning at any time and you need to set up more constraints than you would expect at first. You see that I use three constraints for height for example. I also have an ebook dedicated to it but I must confess that I just gleamed it over. Also some things are still only available from code or by User Defined Runtime Variables. You can do cool stuff like make width of this view twice as large as the width of the other view that can lead to nicely scaling nested views

Comment: Gotchya.  I know this isn't the place to talk about it..But I ALWAYS have expected with and height warnings.

Comment: Well I sometimes left them in as well when things were looking allright but I always regretted that sooner or later. So nowadays I tolerate zero warnings in all my personal projects.

Comment: So in terms of aligning the button's height, when it rotates to landscape, I want the buttons in the middle of the view (not necessarily 150px or a set number).  So if the screen is wider, I still want them to vertically appear in the middle of the view.  Do you know how I'd go about doing this?

Comment: So it's maximum 150px off the bottom and within that limit it should be try to be in the middle of the screen? Then you put <= 150px on 1000, middle align on 750 and =150px on 250  because it needs one fixed offset (probably). This in combination with a hard height like 20px on the button.